# NullReferenceException on String Property

Tags: c#, wpf, string, data-binding, nullreferenceexception

In my program I allow the user to add to a Data Collection bound to a `TreeView`. When the user creates the new node they are allowed to assign it a name. The user writes the nodes name in a `textBox` located in a pop up window. The text from the text box is bound to a property in a ViewModel.

However, I can't seem to get the property or the `string` in the ViewModel to read the value that it is bound to. It just shows up in the debugger as `null`, which is when I get the exception. I've created other windows exactly like this, but for some reason this one doesn't want to work.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TransName}" MaxHeight="20" MinHeight="20" Height="20" Margin="142,24,12,40" Name="textBox1" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged"></TextBox>
```

In the View Model:

```
private string _nodeName;

//Property for Node Name
public string NodeName
{
     get { return _nodeName; }
     set
     {
         _nodeName = value;
         NotifyPropertyChange(() => NodeName);
     }
}
```

Still in the View Model, this is the line in which the Exception occurs

```
//hasSpace is a boolean
hasSpace = _nodeName.Contains(" ");
```

Comment: `_nodeName` is null ofcourse.

Comment: I know, but why? I type in a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the property instead of the backing field. This will control what kind of output can be returned and eliminate the `NullReferenceException`.

Change the property to return empty by default.

```
public string NodeName
{
     get { return _nodeName ?? string.Empty; }
     set
     {
         _nodeName = value;
         NotifyPropertyChange(() => NodeName);
     }
}
```

Then change the ViewModel to use the property:

```
hasSpace = NodeName.Contains(" ");
```

Comment: That worked dude, thanks a lot. I wonder why I only had to do that this time.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful! Eliminating what can produce `null` will reduce the frequency of these kinds of errors.